# Nvidia driver installation disables Cinnamon desktop

Tags: linux, linux-mint, nvidia-graphics-card, cinnamon

In Linux Mint 14 with Cinnamon desktop, after installing the Nvidia drivers it reverts to the gnome desktop.  If I try to manually restart Cinnamon from the command line I get the error:

> Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0.0".
>
> (cinnamon:2294): Clutter-CRITICAL **: Unable to initialize Clutter:
>   Failed to connected to any renderer:  XServer appears to lack required
>   GLX support Window manager error: Unable to initialize Clutter.

How can I get Cinnamon to run normally again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aparently this is a known issue with Nvidia and Linux Mint/Cinnamon: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/72815/mint-update-with-nvidia-breaks-cinnamon